# ¿Cómo ordenar cadenas de caracteres alfabéticamente?

Tags: c++, ordenamiento

Quisiera de su orientación para ordenar alfabéticamente por nombre, estoy usando un método burbuja pero no me funciona y realmente los métodos de ordenamiento me confunde. Gracias.

Intente usar el método *shel* pero tambièn se me dificultó

```
struct persona {
    int codigo;
    string nombre;
    string nombre_Materia;
    double nota1,nota2,nota3,nota_final;
};

persona e[7];

int main(){
    int size;
    cout<<"Ingrese el tamaño de Lista de estudiantes : ";
    cin>>size;
    for(int i=0;i<=size;i++)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Ingrese los datos de la persona: " <<i+1<<"\n";  
        cout <<"Ingrese el codigo: "<<endl;
        cin>>e[i].codigo;
        cout <<"Ingrese el nombre: "<<endl;
        cin>>e[i].nombre;
        cout <<"Ingrese el nombre de la materia: "<<endl;
        cin>>e[i].nombre_Materia;
        cout <<"Ingrese la nota 1: "<<endl;
        cin>>e[i].nota1;
        cout <<"Ingrese la nota 2: "<<endl;
        cin>>e[i].nota2;
        cout <<"Ingrese la nota 3: "<<endl;
        cin>>e[i].nota3;
        e[i].nota_final = e[i].nota1 * 0.30 + e[i].nota2 * 0.30 + e[i].nota3 * 0.40;
    }

    int i, j;
    persona tempo;
    for(i=0; i<size-1; i++)
        for(j=i+1; j<size; j++)
            if( (e[i].nombre > e[j].nombre) || (e[i].nombre  == e[j].nombre && e[i].nombre> e[j].nombre) )
            {
                tempo = e[i];
                e[i] = e[j];
                e[j] = tempo;
            }

    //Declarmaos un for para que lea el vector persona2
    for(int j=0;j<=size;j++)
    {   
        cout<<"Mostrando persona:"<<j+1<<"\n";
        cout<<"Persona: "<<e[j].codigo<<"\n";
        cout<<"Persona: "<<e[j].nombre<<"\n";
        cout<<"Persona: "<<e[j].nombre_Materia<<"\n";
        cout<<"Persona: "<<e[j].nota_final<<"\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenia mucho tiempo sin utilizar burbuja asi que tome el codigo de esta pagina: http://c.conclase.net/orden/?cap=burbuja Aplicando ese codigo con tu ejemplo, tu ordenamiento seria asi:

```
int i, j;
persona tempo;
for (int i = 0;i < size; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j< size-1; j++){
        if (e[j].nombre > e[j+1].nombre){
            tempo = e[j]; 
            e[j] = e[j+1]; 
            e[j+1] = tempo;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo he probado y me ha funcionado, como dato extra, en tu for donde preguntas los datos tenias <= y ahi deberia ser solo el < por que si no se ejecuta una vez extra. Te pongo el codigo de como tenia el codigo final y al parecer funciono, espero te sea de ayuda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct persona
{

    int codigo;
    string nombre;
    string nombre_Materia;
    double nota1, nota2, nota3, nota_final;
};

persona e[7];

int main()
{

    int size;
    cout << "Ingrese el tamaño de Lista de estudiantes : ";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //tenias <= y se ejecutaba uno de mas
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Ingrese los datos de la persona: " << i + 1 << "\n";
        cout << "Ingrese el codigo: " << endl;
        cin >> e[i].codigo;
        cout << "Ingrese el nombre: " << endl;
        cin >> e[i].nombre;
        cout << "Ingrese el nombre de la materia: " << endl;
        cin >> e[i].nombre_Materia;
        cout << "Ingrese la nota 1: " << endl;
        cin >> e[i].nota1;
        cout << "Ingrese la nota 2: " << endl;
        cin >> e[i].nota2;
        cout << "Ingrese la nota 3: " << endl;
        cin >> e[i].nota3;
        e[i].nota_final = e[i].nota1 * 0.30 + e[i].nota2 * 0.30 + e[i].nota3 * 0.40;
    }

    int i, j;
    persona tempo;
    for (int i = 0;i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< size-1; j++){
            if (e[j].nombre > e[j+1].nombre){
                tempo = e[j]; 
                e[j] = e[j+1]; 
                e[j+1] = tempo;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) //tenias <= y se ejecutaba uno de mas
    {
        cout << "Mostrando persona:" << j + 1 << "\n";
        cout << "Persona: " << e[j].codigo << "\n";
        cout << "Persona: " << e[j].nombre << "\n";
        cout << "Persona: " << e[j].nombre_Materia << "\n";
        cout << "Persona: " << e[j].nota_final << "\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int j=0;j<=size;j++)
{   
    cout<<"Mostrando persona:"<<j+1<<"\n";
    cout<<"Persona: "<<e[j].codigo<<"\n";
    cout<<"Persona: "<<e[j].nombre<<"\n";
    cout<<"Persona: "<<e[j].nombre_Materia<<"\n";
    cout<<"Persona: "<<e[j].nota_final<<"\n";
}
```

Reduce el número de iteraciones de este último bucle en 1:

```
for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
//          ^^^^^^
```

Por otro lado, fíjate que la condición para ordernar no tiene demasiado sentido:

```
if( (e[i].nombre > e[j].nombre) || (e[i].nombre  == e[j].nombre && e[i].nombre> e[j].nombre) )
```

La ordenación, entiendo, es ascendente, luego este condicional se puede simplificar bastante, ya que únicamente hay que verificar si el primer nombre es *más grande* que el segundo:

```
if( (e[i].nombre > e[j].nombre) )
```

Por lo demás el código parece funcionar correctamente

Comment: Qué complicado... ¿Por qué no `e[i].nombre.compare(e[j].nombre) < 0`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ¿¿?? Si lo dices por lo de "*verificar si el primer nombre es mśa grande*" su razón de ser la encuentras en que es la línea que ha seguido el OP y le estoy corrigiendo en base a ese camino

Answer (score 1):

Tu aproximación al problema es más complicada de lo necesario. Basta con definir la relación de orden entre instancias de `persona` y delegar la ordenación a un [algoritmo](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) de la librería estándar.

Empecemos por definir un operador menor que (`<`) para objetos `persona`:

```
bool operator <(const persona &a, const persona &b) {
    return a.nombre.compare(b.nombre) < 0;
}
```

Con este operador definido, podrás ordenar:

```
std::sort(std::begin(e), std::end(e));
```

Tu código podría parecerse a esto:

```
struct persona {
    int codigo;
    std::string nombre;
    std::string nombre_Materia;
    double nota1,nota2,nota3,nota_final;
};

bool operator <(const persona &a, const persona &b) {
    return a.nombre.compare(b.nombre) < 0;
}

int main()
{
    persona e[7]{};

    for (auto &p : e)
    {
        std::cin >> p.codigo;
        std::cin.ignore(1);
        std::getline(std::cin, p.nombre);
        std::getline(std::cin, p.nombre_Materia);
        std::cin >> p.nota1;
        std::cin >> p.nota2;
        std::cin >> p.nota3;
        std::cin >> p.nota_final;
    }

    std::sort(std::begin(e), std::end(e));

    for (const auto &p : e)
        std::cout << p.codigo << ' ' << p.nombre << '\n'
            << p.nombre_Materia << ": " << p.nota1 << ' ' << p.nota2 << ' ' << p.nota3 << ' ' << p.nota_final << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[TIO](https://tio.run/##jVPbattAEH3WfMWSQmKBa2yrSVrbBNK0pFBCH1pa6IWwWo2VhdWOupe@mH67O7rZaexCNWLQnpmdM3N2per6eanUdvtMW2VigWKlyQeHsrqCPcaItuVjRJqSnA4PnAYcjSqIGp0nK8UGBD/aBqGo0CUt27UPxWLR1RGWqtzhv/D7OxnQadnFC4q5QQ4FORs3ft76rPX3a22lWcLvJUBOZARxEzKQE6uRIuv3TZ3KsXiC5GnfqsMQnRVy0vFPFFW1dDjKeyAVKzFlEoBmqEpqO0phA8lQCb9d/tg0LSRrZh7JGEic1mIhMIWE85J2RqWtuLoS9WRQZY9PdGmJCWfpDi0xGG1xNKSMeWPfzX/kDBKmywP2Vsjj8Pw4nB2HB@0T1qULe3KhaybHkkXCdNwdL9qCF@lOoe4g/tapZ6AYxGq1U6n5PmNroW62Fvpuz3hL8ggeRm7CJwtxMmzhaZ8U4UEPkOwA6cYbyJrW@2vS3ITtdgpfm18A3mBFlgyVWsJsCq/YZtNJBjN4jUZhHuET9uFLtpdsc/giTUHwQUUTtK8ILtpdHMrgTt3GNVPDO@35HvM8BRpx7QK2tRt7AdelrDWLV2jxkaKXcKPRKqaYwzmHM/a3URuDruIkFJ@l/xnR/WogeOtLpyvZljpnzgt4Hx6iiXAjyTdt7N4/)</kbd>.